# How to get and modify cross-chain asset in contract?

Tags: ink, rust, assets, contracts, cross-chain

I am preparing to create a `smart-contract` on Astar using ink! programming language. The contract's main logic involves modifying the `cross-chain` asset USDT on the statemint chain. After going through all the libraries provided by ink!, I haven't found any relevant interface to modify `cross-chain` assets, specifically the USDT asset with ID 4294969280 on Astar. How can I modify the USDT asset within the ink! contract?

Answer (score 2):

Those are two different things,

#### 1. Interacting with Local USDT Asset (4294969280) on Astar

If you want to interact with pallet-assets assets like USDT, you can use ink! [Chain Extension](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/chain-extension). We have the chain extension for pallet-assets and *it's only available on Shibuya Testnet*.

- Docs - https://use.ink/macros-attributes/chain-extension
- Example ink! contract - https://github.com/swankyhub/chain-extension-contracts/blob/main/examples/assets/lib.rs

**Note:-**
There is a high probability that Chain Extensions might be deprecated and replace with something else, that has same functionality in future, just keep that in mind.

#### 2. Interacting with Remote USDT Asset on Statemint (via XCM)

This will require sending XCM from ink! contracts to Statemint and currently under-development and will be available soon.
Once we have the capability to send XCM messages from ink! contracts, you can not only send/swap assets across parachains but also complex remote transact operations (executing tx on other parachains)